# Google app engine: using a property value as a key

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I have a next entities:

```
class Player(ndb.Model):
    player_id = ndb.IntegerProperty()
```

and

```
class TimeRecord(ndb.Model):
    time = ndb.StringProperty()
```

So TimeRecord's instance is a child of certain instance of Player.
If I need to put a instance of TimeRecord with certain Player I am doing like this:

```
tr = TimeRecord(parent = ndb.Key("Player", Player.query(Player.player_id == int(certain_id)).get().key.integer_id()), time = value)
```

This query is expensive and sophisticated. Accordingly to [doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#filter_by_prop)

```
qry = Account.query(Account.userid == 42)
```

If you are sure that there was just one Account with that userid, you might prefer to use userid as a key. Account.get_by_id(...) is faster than Account.query(...).get().

As I understand I need to change structure of my datastore:

Use player_id as a key of Player and move TimeRecord (time) to property of Players. player_id is unique value.

```
class Player(ndb.Model):
    time = ndb.StringProperty()
```

**Q:** Is that a right approach?

This is similar to mixing different levels of entities inheritance due to as I see every data should be a different entity. And inheritance implemented by ancestor keys.

**Upd:**
But in this case I can store just one TimeRecord value for a certain Player.
And I need a set of TimeRecords for a Player. Is a repeated property solution of this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The redesign you're proposing is essentially, from the POV of a relational database user, a "de-normalization" -- which is almost a bad word in the relational field, but absolutely "normal" (ha ha) once you move into NoSQL.

If you know how things will be queried and updated, de-normalization improves performance (usually) and/or storage (sometimes) at the expense of some flexibility.

Do be aware of the trade-offs, though.  Often, de-normalizing improves performance in querying/reading at the expense of extra burdens in updating -- that can be fine since typically reading is much more frequent than writing, but you need to know whether this is the case for **your** application.

Examining your specific use case, I see definite savings in storage (esp. if you can use a more specialized type for your time property, see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#Date_and_Time) and fewer interactions with the backend (thus better performance) on retrievals.  It also simplifies your code (simplicity is good: fewer risks of bugs, easier to unit-test).

**However**, if saving new "time records" is a very frequent need for a player, the repeated property grows larger and larger (at some point this slows things down despite it still being a single interaction; at worst it would "bump its head" against a single entity's maximum size, which is one megabyte -- sure, that would take many tens of thousands of "time records" per player, but, not knowing your app at all, **I** can't tell whether that's a risk... only **you** can!-).

Queries can also be a problem, again entirely depending on what your app needs.  I'm specifically thinking of inequality queries.  Suppose you need all players with time records greater than, say, `'20141215-10:00:00'`, and smaller than, say, `'20141215-18:00:00'`.  Alas, an inequality query on a repeated property won't do that for you!  That is, if you query for

```
ndb.AND(Player.time > '20141215-10:00:00',
        Player.time < '20141215-18:00:00')
```

you'll get players with a time greater than the first constant and a time less than the second one -- not necessarily the **same** time!  This means the query may return many more players than you wish it would, and you'll need to "filter" the resulting bunch of players in your app's code.

If you had an entity where `time` is **not** a repeated property (such as your original `TimeRecord` entity), then the query analogous to this one would return exactly the bunch of entities of interest (though if you then needed to fetch the **players** sporting those times, you'd then need another interaction with the storage back-end, typically an `ndb.get_multi`, so it's hard to predict performance effects without knowing **much** more about your app's operational parameters!).

That's what de-normalization usually boils down to: trade-offs between different aspect of "desirability" (simplicity, storage saving, fewer backend interactions, smaller amounts of data going to/from the backend -- and we're not even getting into atomic transactions and applicability of async techniques!-) -- trade-offs that can be made only with some deep understanding of an app's operational parameters.

Indeed it may be worth deploying two or more prototypes, each to a small set of users, to get actual **data** about how they perform (the new Cloud Monitoring offer can help with the "get actual data" part), before choosing a "definitive" (ha!) architecture -- despite the fact that migrating the data from the prototypes to the "definitive" schema will incur overhead-effort needs.

And if the app is an overnight success and suddenly you get tens of thousands of queries per second, rather than the orders-of-magnitude fewer you had planned for, the performance characteristics may just as suddenly change to the point the pain of re-architecting and migrating again may be warranted (a good problem to have, for sure, but still...).